# Excel if statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

Trying to make this scenario work -

Have to reference a range of cells in a column in another work sheet and if the values are like new york 4th street it must populate as new york or must populate the default value.

=(IF(Dashboard!GT14=New York - C4) , New York , Dashboard!GT14) - this does not work

couple of other scenarios also do not work

Suggessions welcome

Comment: Firstly, both instances of "New York" need to be in quotes. Secondly, subtracting C4 from "New York" makes no sense.

Comment: Do you want to test if **any** cell in the range contains the required text or if **all** the cells contain the required text ??

Comment: Rolled back as edit fixed the code.

Answer (score 0):

First, New York should be "New York".

And what is C4 ?

For example, if C4 is "Boston" and you want to know if GT14 is "New York Boston", you have to put GT14 = CONCAT("New York ";C4)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("new york",LOWER(Dashboard!GT14))),"New York",Dashboard!GT14)
```

assuming you have a full address in GT14 and that you want to check if New York is part of that.

Comment: This is exaclty what i was looking for . One more question though how can i do If find new york then New York or if princeton then Princeton if London then London else default value

Comment: =IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("new york",LOWER(Dashboard!GT14))),"New York", IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("london",LOWER(Dashboard!GT14))),"London", IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("princeton",LOWER(Dashboard!GT14))),"Princeton", IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("wilmington",LOWER(Dashboard!GT14))),"Wilmington",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("budapest",LOWER(Dashboard!GT14))),"Budapest",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("rancho cordova",LOWER(Dashboard!GT14))),"Rancho Cordova",Dashboard!GT14))))))